# Query to return records after a qualifying date

Tags: sql, date, between

fairly new/beginner level to sql as I have been learning from free online courses.

I am currently trying to return all records from a dataset after a qualifying date. Clients may show up once or multiple times in the table. I only want to return the clients if they have had at least 2 events where the first 2 events being within 1 month of each other. I have tried using HAVING and CASE. I've thought about declaring the start date but as all the initial dates are different, im not sure how it is possible.

Table example:
client id, record id, last name, first name, dob, event date, event completed (y/n)

Not necessarily looking for the answer but maybe some direction on how to write this query.

---

Edit:
Thank you for your feedback. Here are some more details.

I currently have a table with all records that looks like this:

| recordid | clientid | lastname | firstname | dob | eventdate | eventcomplete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/1/2021 | Y |
| 2 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/19/2021 | Y |
| 3 | 123 | a | john | - | 3/2/2021 | Y |
| 4 | 456 | b | david | - | 2/15/2021 | Y |
| 5 | 789 | c | peter | - | 1/6/2021 | Y |
| 6 | 789 | c | peter | - | 3/17/2021 | Y |

I would like to write a query where I can return all clients that have had at least 2 events, where the first 2 events are within 1 month of each other.

So from my example table, I would only return records for client 123, because client 456 only had 1 event and client 789 had 2 events that were more than a month a part.

| recordid | clientid | lastname | firstname | dob | eventdate | eventcomplete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/1/2021 | Y |
| 2 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/19/2021 | Y |
| 3 | 123 | a | john | - | 3/2/2021 | Y |

My current thought is to insert another record id that would look like this (below) and some how compare the event dates between records 1 and 2. Is this the correct way to go about this? my end goal is to use this filtered data in a visualization showing members with qualifying events.

| eventcountid | recordid | clientid | lastname | firstname | dob | eventdate | eventcomplete |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/1/2021 | Y |
| 2 | 2 | 123 | a | john | - | 1/19/2021 | Y |
| 3 | 3 | 123 | a | john | - | 3/2/2021 | Y |
| 1 | 4 | 456 | b | david | - | 2/15/2021 | Y |
| 1 | 5 | 789 | c | peter | - | 1/6/2021 | Y |
| 2 | 6 | 789 | c | peter | - | 3/17/2021 | Y |

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions!

Comment: Please add a few rows of sample data and the expected result.

Comment: Which database are you using? Postgres, mysql, other?

Comment: You need to look into window functions. They are implemented differently in various databases. If you are using `Postgres`, then you can use a `lag` function by partitioning over clientid and sorting by recordid or eventdate

Comment: I am using Oracle